# How to get IMDb info in Nautilus properties?

Tags: nautilus, python, nautilus-actions, nautilus-script, nautilus-extensions

I want to see IMDb information about movie files on my Nautilus properties screen, using Nautilus scripts or actions.

---

It's a really complex thing to do, I understand that, but the article [Extending Nautilus Context Menus using Nautilus Actions, Scripts and Python Extensions](https://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/08/29/extending-nautilus-context-menus-using-nautilus-actions-scripts-and-python-extensions/) explains how to do it.

It just needs to be updated for 2017 (the article was written in 2010). The Google code link that article gave is abandoned.

I'm not too strict on implementation, but if I could right-click on a movie file and see IMDb information that'd be good.

[IMDbpy](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'm not keen on Python, but what if you were to right click on the file, select custom scripts, then select option `IMDB` and a google chrome window was automatically opened with `imbd` + the file name in search results? Something like that I think I can do.

Comment: The python source of the IMDB-information extension is apparently [here](https://github.com/anvivora/saravanant/blob/master/blog/nautilusScripts/imdb-property-page.py). I have not tested it, nor have I checked that the repo is indeed just an export from google-code.

Answer (score 1):

So for starters in Ubuntu 18.04 it works this way:

1. Install package `python-nautilus`
2. Get Test Extension from [here](https://projects-old.gnome.org/nautilus-python/documentation/html/nautilus-python-overview-example.html#id2684063) and save as `TestExtension.py`
3. Copy `TestExtension.py` to `/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions` (with `sudo`)
4. Change to that directory and adapt permissions: `sudo chmod u+x TestExtension.py`
5. Restart Nautilus: `killall nautilus`
6. Klick with the right mouse button on some file and you will see `Showing <Filename>` in the context menu.
7. Adapt this [imdb script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anvivora/saravanant/master/blog/nautilusScripts/imdb-property-page.py) to your environment.